# How can I output debugging messages to the log with PHP on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, debugging

What PHP statements can I use (e.g. echo/print/log_message) to output to the system log with PHP on Google App Engine?

I tried with very simple print, echo, log_message statements but everything I try gives me errors. I read that such statements are not part of the PHP on GAE.

Comment: Note: the log output is only visible after deploying to the server: see here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/logs/

Answer (score 4):

to output a debug log in app engine I use:

`syslog(LOG_DEBUG,'Your string');`

For more information try [app engine PHP docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/logs/), important to notice that they don't mention the LOG_DEBUG there but it works fine.

If you want to see the DEBUG level in the local development server started with `dev_appserver.py` use `--log_level=debug`. You can read more about local development server [on the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/tools/local-devserver-command).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [syslog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php) to write to the applications logs.

In production you will see these logs in the admin console for your application.